# c# scope/typing/assignment question

Tags: c#-3.0, c#-4.0

Hi there another quick question.

I would like to create a variable object so that depending on the value of something, it gets cast as needed. e.g.

```
var rule;
switch (seqRuleObj.RuleType) {
                case SeqRuleObj.type.Pre :
                    rule = new preConditionRuleType();
                    rule = (preConditionRuleType)seqRuleObj.Rule;
                    break;
                case SeqRuleObj.type.Post :
                    rule = new postConditionRuleType();
                    rule = (postConditionRuleType)seqRuleObj.Rule;
                    break;
                case SeqRuleObj.type.Exit :
                    rule = new exitConditionRuleType();
                    rule = (exitConditionRuleType)seqRuleObj.Rule;
                    break;
                default :
                    break;
            }
            String result;
            foreach (sequencingRuleTypeRuleConditionsRuleCondition cond in rule.ruleConditions.ruleCondition) {

      ....../ blah
}
```

so basically this will not work.  c# will not allow me to create an new object in every case as the name is aleady defined.

i can just paste the foreach loop into each case but that to me is such a waste, as the objects are exactly the same in all but name.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! As far as I can tell, this question has nothing to do with dynamic objects. This is a scope/typing/assignment question. Please retitle appropriately - a properly titled question will get more of the right people looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these types inherit from a common class or implement a common interface?  If so, then instead of using `var rule`, declare `rule` to be of the base type/interface.

If they do not have a common class/interface and you have control over these types, then create a base class/interface for them.

Comment: +1: This type of situation is exactly what class inheritance is for.

Comment: hi thanks for reply.  Yes they derive from common type.  I declare rule as this and is ok, except in foreach still says use of unassigned local var

Comment: doh! I had my default case empty.  Thanks again for help.